# Where to use Local inner classes

Tags: java

Could you please explain me clearly "where do we need to use local inner classes"?

Example:

```
public class LocalTest
{

    int b=30;
    void display()
    {
        class Local{ 
            void msg()
            {

                 System.out.println(b);
            }       
        }

        Local l = new Local();
        l.msg();
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        LocalTest lt = new LocalTest();
        lt.display();
    }
}
```

Here `Local class` is a Local inner class. It is useful only for  `display()`. In which type of situations do we use these local inner classes ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: THat one links to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478804/advantage-of-local-classes-java/479937#479937 which I think is even better.

Comment: When you feel the need to use a local inner class, the immediate question that should come to mind is: Is it not time to refactor?

Answer (score 0):

Main reason is when we need to implement some interface locally and pass it somewhere, but we want to add more methods to the implementation, so anonymous implementation does not fit:

```
public static void Main (String [] args) throws Exception
{
    class MyRunnable extends Runnable
    {
        private boolean complete = false;

        public synchronized void waitComplete () throws InterruptedException
        {
            while (!complete) wait ();
        }

        @Override
        public void run ()
        {
            // Do something useful

            synchronized (this)
            {
                complete = true;
                notifyAll ();
            }
        }
    }

    MyRunnable r = new MyRunnable ();
    new Thread (r).start ();

    // Do something in parallel with new thread

    r.waitComplete (); // We forgot about Thread.join ()
}
```

Comment: You don't actually need a *local* inner class for that, however. An ordinary inner class would suffice.

Comment: @Dolda2000 Anonymous inner class can always be replaced with local inner class, which in turn can be replaced with non-local inner class, which can be replaced with static inner class which can be replaced with top-level class.  Local inner classes are just syntax sugar.

Comment: Sure. :) The point rather being that from only the *characterization* of the issue that you made, it is not clear why one would want to make it a local class rather than a member class, or even, indeed, a top-level class.

Answer (score -1):

I'd argue it might have two uses:

- You don't want to pollute the namespace outside the function in question with a class that is only used inside the function anyway.
- You want to use any (`final`) variables declared inside the function without having to pass them explicitly through a constructor.